# ggplot2 - Stacking / dodging bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am having issues with making barchart in which the y axis is not count, but value from variables.

I use `stat=identity`, which is fine for one variable. But what if I have two variables and want to create a stacking / dodging barchart?

I have some mock data here:

```
foo <- data.frame(case=c('A','B','C'), var1=rnorm(3), var2=rnorm(3))
```

So my three cases on x-axis are A, B, and C. I want to plot the values of var1 and var2 as bars. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, changed your sample data. When making data frame you don't need `cbind()` because in this case you make all columns as factors.

```
foo <- data.frame(case=c('A','B','C'), var1=rnorm(3), var2=rnorm(3))
```

To use two variables for barplot easiest way would be to melt the data from wide to long format.

```
library(reshape2)
foo.long<-melt(foo)
foo.long
  case variable      value
1    A     var1  0.7150827
2    B     var1 -0.5279363
```

Now use `value` as y values and `variable` for the fill. `stat="identity"` and `position="dodge"` will ensure that actual values are plotted and bars are dogged.

```
ggplot(foo.long, aes(case,value,fill=variable))+
      geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I also changed the mock data in my question so as not to confuse future readers.

Comment: Hmm I just encountered a real-life instance where all of my columns in data frame (imported from Excel) are vectors. Could you explain or point me to resource about this behavior? When does R think a column is factor?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it possible to control which variable gets plotted first from ggplot? Or do I have to reorder the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I am not answering the question, in the sens I am not using `ggplot2`. But, if you want to use the data.frame  in its wide format, one other way is to use ``barchart`from`lattice`package. To get`ggplot2`theme, I am using`latticeExtra`. Using @Didzis data:

```
library(latticeExtra)
 barchart(var1+var2~case,data=foo,origin=0,
     par.settings = ggplot2like(),axis=axis.grid,auto.key=TRUE)
```

[image]