# ggplot multiple binary variables in groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

my data looks like this:

```
groupvar    var1   var2   var3    var4
group1      1       1       0       0
group1      0       1       1       1
group3      1       0       1       0
group4      1       1       0       1
group4      0       0       0       1
group2      0       1       1       0
```

I would like to have an output that looks like this:

[Some made up data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dvZj.png)

I'm not too sure how to go about this, does it require reshaping the data to long somehow?  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I have spent a good deal of time searching, it's very possible I'm bad at searching but if you could direct me in the right place rather than downvoting that would be soooooo much better.

Edit2: I don't quite know how to use dput but here's my output from it:

```
structure(list(groupvar = c("group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", 
"group2", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group1", "group1"),
var1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), var2 = c(0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), var3 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0), var4 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), .Names = c("groupvar", 
"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: You probably got down voted because you provided data in to format that takes more than one second to load. Better use `dput`

Comment: You can use `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather` to reshape your dataset from wide to long, which is then easy to plot in ggplot2

Comment: look at http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html for plotting after melting. Also look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182938/ggplot2-stacking-dodging-bar-chart

Comment: Ah, I offered a visual representation of the data because I cannot share the data.  I'll try make the data I posted and use dput now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- read_csv("groupvar,    var1,   var2,   var3,   var4
                group1,      1,       1,       0,       0
                group1,      0,       1,       1,       1
                group3,      1,       0,       1,       0
                group4,      1,       1,       0,       1
                group4,      0,       0,       0,       1
                group2,      0,       1,       1,       0")

td <- d %>% 
    gather(var, val, -1) %>% 
    group_by(groupvar, var) %>% 
    summarize(tot = sum(val))


ggplot(td, aes(groupvar, tot, fill = var)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it!  I had a feeling it was a combination of reshaping and summarizing but I could not wrap my head around how exactly to do it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Glad it was helpful! (you may want to mark it as correct)

Comment: Can I ask why the third argument to gather is -1, and do I need to rename my variables to the same prefix if they do not share a prefix like var?

Comment: The third argument to gather specifies the columns to gather. So in this case, all but the first one. You should be fine if they don't have the same prefix, but I'm not sure... I may be misunderstanding your question. But basically you'll want to try to get your data in a tidy format. See http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html

Comment: Yep that makes sense.  Seriously thank you so much for help and for the paper.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Comment: How would you do this if the variables have different names? Not var1 var2 etc but Action, Romance, Thriller, etc

Comment: Same sort of thing. Just need to gather the multiple columns into a single column, and use that column as the fill/color.